# Does putExtras() unarchive and then archive the extras again?

Tags: java, android, extras

I'm working on an android application project, and I have a scenario where I send data between activities in the following order:

Activity1 sends two extras via the `putExtra()` method.
Activity2 receives them, but never works with them. Then depending on a button user clicks I need to send the first extra from Activity1 to Activity3 OR the second extra from Activity1 to Activity4.

So, my question is - what would be better - to use directly `putExtras()` and send both extras to the following Activity3 or 4, or to unarchive the extras in Activity2 and send only the correct one to Activity3 or 4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the amount of data, if it's minuscule then it doesn't matter and is worth saving the code clutter in your activity.

Comment: Thank you, It's small amout if data, so I'll just send both of them.